# how to redirect events in remote with WPF dispatcher

Tags: wpf, events, queue, dispatcher

i'm new here and i'm looking for a clarification about dispatcher:
i need to intercept mouse events from a client and send it to a server (pushing it in server's dispatcher), how can i take an event and send it before it is pushed into local (client) dispatcher queue?
I tried something like

```
UIElement.MouseMoveEvent
```

catching handling but it goes to dispatching

thanks a lot

Comment: You must be confusing the `Dispatcher` class with something totally different. That is *not* what the `Dispatcher` class is for. Perhaps you should tell us what you're *actually* trying to do, so that we might suggest the correct course of action? *i need to intercept mouse events from a client and send it to a server*... why would you want to do that?

Comment: this is in fact the problem of sending data between clients and servers. The input data is collected in MouseEventHandler and all the information you need to send (such as mouse location, ...) will be sent to the server somehow. So technically this problem should be rephrased and it's in fact not related to WPF or events.

Comment: @Sheridan I'm trying to do an application for remote screen control: i'm trying to block the events on the client and redirect them and show the result on the server (remote screen).